# Print pg_search params to Rails 5 template page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, pg-search

I have a products page that is filterable with `pg_search` gem.  What I would like to do is create a breadcrumb that lists the search params onto the page.

If my search url looks like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/products?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=modern&query=stone&query=limestone&commit=Search` I would like to print `modern stone limestone` to the page.

**products_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @products = if params[:query]
               @albums = Album.where(name: params[:query])
               Product.search_for(params[:query])
              else
               @albums = Album.where(name: 'products')
                 Product.order(:name)
               end
end
```

**index.html.erb**
This is what I tried, but realized that it lists ALL the tags, which I only need the tags that are part of the search params

```
<ul class="product-index-breadcrumb">
  <% @products.each do |p| %>
    <% p.tags.each do |t| %>
      <li><%= t.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your URL e.g array string adding `[]`  if you keep this then it only without `[]` then it takes only last value like `limestone`, 
  after modification URL then it will look like this `http://http://127.0.0.1:3000/products?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query[]=modern&query[]=stone&query[]=limestone`

then if you write like

```
<%= params[:query] %>
```

it will return

```
["modern", "stone", "limestone"]
```

now you can run a loop like

```
<ul>
    <% params[:query].each do |query_params|  %>
        <li><%= query_params %></li>
    <% end  %>
</ul>
```

then output is

- modern
- stone
- limestone